# Javascript async XHR to PHP - acting as synchronous

Tags: javascript, php, nginx, promise, xmlhttprequest

Application using JavaScript (via Firefox), back-end PHP served by nginx:

```
PHP 7.4.22 (fpm-fcgi)
Zend 3.4.0
nginx 1.20.1
RHEL 8
```

In the browser, I launch five simultaneous XHR back to PHP:

```
/* 
What we are doing here is grouping the enumerated array of fetchNodes
calls under a single 'Promise.all' object.  As these complete, 
the promises will settle and either resolve or reject.

--> fetchPlan is a five-element array, one for each XHR (AJAX) call.
--> fetchNodes returns a single Promise object.
*/
Promise.all( fetchPlan.map(oneFetch => fetchNodes(oneFetch.fetchOptions)) )
    .then( function(){} )
    .catch( function(){} )
    .finally ( function() {} );

/* fetchNodes eventually ends up with jQuery AJAX: */
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax(options)
        .done(resolve)
        .fail(reject);
});
```

Back on the server, nginx is showing these incoming events.  Note the timestamps:
I expected all five to come in at the same time.

```
[10/Aug/2021:14:57:46 +0000] "POST /<my endpoint?package_1> HTTP/1.1" 200
[10/Aug/2021:14:57:49 +0000] "POST /<my endpoint?package_2> HTTP/1.1" 200
[10/Aug/2021:14:57:50 +0000] "POST /<my endpoint?package_3> HTTP/1.1" 200
[10/Aug/2021:14:58:03 +0000] "POST /<my endpoint?package_4> HTTP/1.1" 200
[10/Aug/2021:14:58:04 +0000] "POST /<my endpoint?pacakge_5> HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Inside the PHP script (router), I mark the timestamp of when a request hits the script and when it completes.
Again, I expected these to start at the same time.  They are executing serially.
This is "**all PHP**" - data is coming from APCu cache; there is no call to any I/O or socket of any type (other than APCu).

```
[10-Aug-2021 14:57:46 UTC] --> Starting fetch: package_1
[10-Aug-2021 14:57:49 UTC] --> Ending fetch: package_1

[10-Aug-2021 14:57:49 UTC] --> Starting fetch: package_2
[10-Aug-2021 14:57:50 UTC] --> Ending fetch: package_2

[10-Aug-2021 14:57:50 UTC] --> Starting fetch: package_3
[10-Aug-2021 14:58:02 UTC] --> Ending fetch: package_3

[10-Aug-2021 14:58:04 UTC] --> Starting fetch: package_4
[10-Aug-2021 14:58:04 UTC] --> Ending fetch: package_4

[10-Aug-2021 14:58:04 UTC] --> Starting fetch: package_5
[10-Aug-2021 14:58:06 UTC] --> Ending fetch: package_5
```

Since the write to nginx access.log happens after the http request completes, I think what is happening here is PHP is behaving synchronously -- even though this should be five separate invocations of PHP from five separate incoming requests.  Unless PHP is keeping all five inside a single PHP session?  I'm weak on this knowledge.

So...how do I investigate this and fix it?  My goal is for all five POST requests to be handled by five separate PHP threads/workers - *at the same time*.

Comment: since NGINX is logging the request times as the same as the start times in PHP it's not PHP that's causing this - it's either NGINX (unlikely) the browser (possibly) or your code - most likely - but you haven't shown the code that creates the array you pass to `Promise.all` - perhaps the code that creates those promises is wrong - are you using async/await in a loop by any chance?

Comment: as @Bravo says, let's see the JS code - while `Promise.all` should execute those promises simultaneously, it's possible that you're accidentally firing those requests one after the other as you create the promises. Maybe not, but until I've seen the code I think it's the most likely explanation

Comment: Thanks - I modified the JS snippet to better show the way I'm using Promise.all.  Also - on other pages in this app with completely separate .js files being loaded and firing unrelated XHR on domReady - I'm seeing the same 'serial' behavior.  I don't get it...

Comment: @Bravo also...not sure if it matters, but when I watch the outgoing XHR from the browser inspector, it appears that all five of them are outbound at the same time.

Comment: appears? what's the time on the console for each of these requests - that would imply that either the browser is pretending the requests are *simultaneous* but is in fact doing them serially, or NGNIX is only doing one request at a time ... or ... you've set `async:false` for `$.ajax`

Comment: by the way, `$.ajax` returns a Promise-like object, so, you can dispense with the `return new Promsie` stuff and just `return $.ajax(options)`

Comment: I mean, the instant the Promise.all is hit, I see five XHR get requests show up in the browser console.  Immediately.  They each 'sit there' until the data comes back.  Is there a better way I can tell the exact time the browser sent the XHR request(s)?

Comment: @Bravo I think I found the problem - I'm doing 'session_start()' at the entrypoint of the receiving PHP script.  So every AJAX call hits that.  I thought that meant PHP would reuse any existing session and would be a good idea.  If I comment that line out, this application behaves asynchronously as I expected.  Since I don't use session for anything, maybe I just leave it out then.